# How to delete white space in a string parsed (ruby) ? (delete doesn't work)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, integer, removing-whitespace

I don't understand why but my string whitespaces doesn't want to remove. 
It comes from an array parsed from a Google sheets. 
The interest is to convert it to an integer in order to treat it then.

My code returns "2 217 500 €".
Then I use the method .delete(" "+"€") and it returns "2 217 500". 
If I try to convert it from an integer (with .to_i) it return 2.
I also tried .gsub and .split method it doesn't work too.

Did someone knows why it doesn't work, or another method to do it ?

Here is my code :

```html
spreadsheet_id = '18YgC24_HRA6cddc71vynatoMwUQpToQHtGE_p1vc2Xk'
    range = 'League_billing_total!A2:B'

    response4 = service.get_spreadsheet_values(spreadsheet_id, range).to_json
    puts response4
    # {"majorDimension":"ROWS","range":"League_billing_total!A2:B1000","values":[["Total 2018","1 575 764 €"],["Budget","2 217 500 €"]]}

    parse_response4 = JSON.parse(response4) 
    puts parse_response4
    # {"majorDimension"=>"ROWS", "range"=>"League_billing_total!A2:B1000", "values"=>[["Total 2018", "1 575 764 €"], ["Budget", "2 217 500 €"]]}

    flatte = parse_response4['values']
    puts flatte # [["Total 2018", "1 575 764 €"], ["Budget", "2 217 500 €"]]

    @starters_total = flatte.flatten!

    puts @starters_total        # ["Total 2018", "1 575 764 €", "Budget","2 217 500 €"]
    puts @starters_total[3] # "2 217 500 €"

    @budget_2018_new_deals = @starters_total[3].delete(" "+"€") 
    puts @budget_2018_new_deals # "2 217 500"
    puts @budget_2018_new_deals.to_i # 2
```

Comment: Strange, if I execute `"2 217 500 €".gsub("€","").gsub(" ","").to_i` I get; `2217500`.

Comment: What did you try with `gsub`?

Comment: Also `"2 217 500 €".scan(/\d+/).join`.

Comment: Yes in irb test "2 217 500 €".gsub("€","").gsub(" ","").to_i works for me too but it post 2 in real situation
And .scan(/\d+/).join works ! Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

I would just remove everything from the string that isn't a digit:

```
"2 217 500 €".gsub(/\D/, '')
#=> "2217500"
```

Comment: This. _Always_ use whitelisting, not blacklisting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove only leading and trailing whitespace (like PHP's trim) you can use `.strip`, but if you want to remove all whitespaces, you can use `.gsub(/\s+/, "")` instead .